# Force User Registration before visitng Checkout Page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration

Is there any built in option available in Wordpress/WooCommerce which forces user to register/login before going to the checkout page?

There is an option in  WooCommerce >> Settings >> Accounts >> Account Creation >> Allow customers to create an account during checkout

But this option not works if a non-logged in user visits a website, add item to the cart and go to the checkout page.

I want that user must register before viewing the checkout page or at least in the checkout page.

Thanks

Comment: See here for this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28291427/7956952

Answer (score 1):

If you have the:

"WooCommerce >> Settings >> Accounts >> Account Creation >> Allow customers to create an account during checkout" turned on

and

"WooCommerce >> Settings >> Accounts >> Account Creation >> Allow customers to place orders without an account" turned off.(see image below);

[image: WooCommerce Setting Example]

The non-logged in user will have to be registered to purchase the product and will be registered automatically with the information they put into the forms at checkout.

See here for the documentation on WooCommerce: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/

Comment: No it won't works. My payment method is PAYPAL. Please check my link here: [website](https://sglobaltraders.com/checkout/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the facts of their shitty UX.